# Can there be dead ends in Ford fulkerson based algorithm?

Tags: max-flow, ford-fulkerson

Can we remove those edges which don't lead to sink t during DFS in ford fulkerson merhod similar to what we do in dinics algorithm? If not, can you please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Because in ford fulkerson, we can use an augmenting path through reverse edge to reduce a forward edge flow, which might make the forward edge usable in next iteration of DFS. So, removing an edge is not a good idea. Whereas in dinic, dead v can't become usable again once it's dead since there is no chance flow of an edge going away from v be reduced due to lack of reverse edges.